# Difference between applying for ESTA by smartphone app and online web form

Tags: esta

I have applied my ESTA using online web form from my laptop.
My friend has applied for ESTA using smartphone app.
When compared, our experience was quite different. The app has apparently far more steps; it scans your passport and 3D face scan. By scanning passport was meant NFC scan I assume, downloading data from the chip embedded chip in your plastic hard part of you passport, including biometrical data.

In the web app, you only upload photo/scan of you main passport page.
Which does include your photo. No taking picture of your face. No downloading of your biometrical data. No need to have passport by your hand, you already have a photo/scan of it.

The smartphone app is not even mentioned on any of the official sites:
https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/
https://www.usa.gov/visa-waiver-esta

You have open the https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/ link in mobile web browser and only there you get a button in the page header saying "Open in App" which will take you to the app store.

Would it give one any advantage to have it done by the much more nosy app compared to the more restrained web application?

Comment: For New Zealand the application is cheaper with the app than with the online portal. However the app is absolutely terrible and crashes all the time so most people shell out the extra cash for going online.

Comment: https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/national-media-release/esta-mobile-app-launches-40-countries-and-24-languages CBP is probably using it as a trial for a future Australian-ETA-like system.

Comment: Note that the biometrical data read from the chip is most likely only the photograph (and anyone with an NFC-enabled phone may do so if they are in possession of the passport). But facial matching is trendy for ETA systems around the world now, despite the accessibility issues and the inability of most governments to design a user-friendly mobile app.